# Multiprocessing in Python not working

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am webscraping using lxml. I have over 1000 company names in one file(stock_names) and same number of URLs in another file(stocks_URL).

It's taking endless, more than 20 mins to finish executing. So, I tried using multiprocessing concept in my program. For sample testing, I am using 10 comp.names and their URLs. When I run the program, it is finishing in around 8 seconds. It is taking same time with or without multiprocessing. I am not sure why it is not executing in lesser time when multiprocessing is used.

Below is my input:

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import texttable as tt
from multiprocessing import Process

class bcolors:
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BGGREEN = '\033[42m'


def main(url, stock_names):
    page = requests.get(url)
    tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
    percentage = tree.xpath('//span[@class="grnb_20"]/text()')
    if percentage and int(percentage[0].rstrip('%')) > 70:
        people = tree.xpath('//a[@class="bl_11"]/u/text()')
        percentage = bcolors.BGGREEN + str(percentage[0]) + bcolors.ENDC
        x.append([stock_names, percentage, people])

def stocks():
    with open('stocks_url') as urlfile, open('stock_names') as stock_names:
        for url, stock_names in zip(urlfile, stock_names):
            q = Process(target=main(url, stock_names))
            q.start()
            q.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tab = tt.Texttable()
    x = []
    p = Process(target=stocks)
    p.start()
    p.join()
    tab.add_rows(x)
    tab.header(['Company', 'Percentage', 'People'])
    tab.set_deco(tab.HEADER | tab.VLINES)
    print tab.draw()
```

Below is the output:

```
$ time python stocks_3.py 
...
...
...

real    0m7.904s
user    0m0.448s
sys     0m0.208s
```

Comment: Join blocks until completion
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#process-and-exceptions

Comment: collect all your threads in some sort of collection, and then when you are done simply `map(lambda thread : thread.join(), _list)`. If you need to wait till they are all finished to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, cause you use `join()`

from [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join):

> Block the calling thread until the process whose join() method is called terminates or until the optional timeout occurs.

So in one iteration you call `p.join()`, then main thread stops until job is finished in the new process. Therefore you gain nothing from multiprocessing.

**Solution**

Usually people use multithreading rather than multiprocessing in such case. Whether you use multithreading or multoprocessing, remember to **call `join` after you've assigned all tasks to new threads/processes**.

```
def stocks():
    subp = []
    with open('stocks_url') as urlfile, open('stock_names') as stock_names:
        for url, stock_names in zip(urlfile, stock_names):
            q = Process(target=main(url, stock_names))
            subp.append(q)
            q.start()

    for p in subp:
        p.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tab = tt.Texttable()
    x = []
    stocks()
    tab.add_rows(x)
    tab.header(['Company', 'Percentage', 'People'])
    tab.set_deco(tab.HEADER | tab.VLINES)
    print tab.draw()
```

No need to create another process in main.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the execution time is still around 8 seconds.

real    0m7.486s
user    0m0.376s
sys     0m0.232s

Comment: @user3198755 It's possible that one of your scraping task takes 8s.

Comment: I added the following and checked the execution time for each call: 

            start_time = datetime.now()  
            q = Process(target=main(url, stock_names))  
            subp.append(q)  
            q.start()  
            end_time = datetime.now()  
            print end_time - start_time  

00.803441  
00.750572  
00.790796  
00.749439  
00.770399  
00.607399  
00.752350  
00.613330  
00.607121  
00.612592

Comment: @user3198755 How many cores do you have? Try print out `start_time` for each task and see if they are really executed simultaneously.

Comment: @lalke9m: I am running on a quad core processor cpu. The start_time shows that they are not executed parallely but in sequence

Comment: @user3198755 By `start_time` I mean the actual start time of each `main` function, so you should put `start_time = datetime.now()` in `main`.